# Regression analysis of different ranges in percent?

Tags: regression, scales

I have two variables, both percentages but have been converted to decimal numbers, and one variable ranges from roughly 15-30 percent and the other ranges from 55-70 percent. The lower range is my response, dependent variable. The residuals are really high but should have some correlation. Would scaling one of the variables help and what type of scaling? Logarithmic?

I hope I explained my question well. I am not an expert statistician but trying to learn. Any help would be appreciated. BTW, I am using R.

EDIT
Would scaling one of the variables help lower the residuals?

Comment: What is a model you are fitting?

Comment: Why "should [your residuals] have some correlation"? Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) w/ some data, or post some plots?

Comment: @Aksakal, I believe linear. It is just simple regression model in R.

Comment: @gung, I may have misspoke. I am saying there is some correlation with the variables. Better than what I am currently outputting at least. They may or not be good. I'll try to have some examples soon

Comment: @geomatix you write "Would scaling one of the variables help" but your readers are left wonder "help what?" Help 'lower' the residuals? Help interpretability? Help out around the house? Please edit your question to reflect your intention.

Comment: @Alexis, sorry. I wish help around the house but no, would they help lower the residuals.